# How to run a job on master and multiple nodes at a time in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I have configured my node which is connected to the master, on "Restrict where this project can be run" section I am able add the node name ,by which the job is only running on the node machine .My aim is run the job on master and node (on both) ,how to achieve ,Please help !!

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins job can run in only one node either master or agent.

When you configure the job with "Restrict where this project can be run" then the job runs in that agent only.

So if you wish job to run either master or agent which ever is free don't configure the property "Restrict where this project can be run" leave it empty.

Configure the master node usage to "Use this node as much as possible".

After configuring like above now both master and agent are ready to build the job.

Comment: I want to run on both master and node ,for that what I need to do ?

Comment: By default one build can be executed, to have multiple instances of build for a Job, You have to enable "Execute concurrent builds if necessary" in Job's configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try giving master,slave_name in "Restrict where this project can be run" at a time.

Comment: comma separator is not working in  "Restrict where this project can be run" .I have tried master,slave_name but its taking that as "master,slave_name" single unit .

Comment: master&&slave and master || slave. check this once

Comment: Its also showing the same problem "(pending—There are no nodes with the label ‘master&&datum_servers’)" . And while trying with "master || slave" it is only running on slave node .

Comment: can u check this option "This build is parameterized" and check Label option in it.